# How to encrypt and sync folder between a NAS and 2 Macs

Tags: encryption, nas, dmg

I have an iMac and a MacBook and also a Synology NAS that supports Btrfs.

I would like to move my working documents inside a NAS shared folder that is sync with my computers.

Synology provide Cloud Station Drive that is a sort of personal dropbox

The only issue is encryption.
Synology shared folders can be encrypted but, as far as I know, the have to be mounted by the NAS to work. I don't think in any way is possible to decrypt folder client side.

The only other way I can think to accomplish this is to use a spare encrypted DMG

I'm not sure if working and saving documents all day long inside the DMG could bring some sort of data lost or file corruption.

Comment: What exactly is your question?